# Find all uses of division operator in python code

Tags: python, regex

I want to find all of the instances in my `python` code in which the division operator `/` is used. My first instinct is to use a regular expression. The expression needs to filter out non-division uses of `/`, i.e. path names. The best I've come up with is `[ A-z0-9_\)]/[ A-z0-9_\(]`. This would find the division operator in

```
foo/bar
foo / bar
foo/(bar*baz)
foo / 10
1/2
etc...
```

but would also match the `/`s in something like `"path/to/my/file"`

Can anybody come up with a better regex? Alternatively, is there a non-regex way to find division?

edit: To clarify:

I don't necessarily need to use `python` to do this. I just want to know the location of division operators so I can manually/visually inspect them. I can ignore commented code

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, do you mean to say you're using Python to read a text file containing Python code?

Comment: Don't use a regular expression for this. You need a proper parse of the code. Look at module `astroid`. It will find all AST nodes with division operators for you.

Comment: To complicate things: it is possible to have newlines in a division line (or any single Python line, really). And what about integer division `//`?

Comment: Would be good if you could describe what you want to do with the instances of the division operator use. Do you want to visually inspect them? Transform them? etc.

Comment: you could run your code in python 2 with the `-3` mode to be warned against those division cases

Comment: What about division symbols in comments, or in commented code? Also, what do you need this for? There might be a better way to achieve that.

Comment: Also, do you want to do this _in Python_, or purely with Regex, e.g. in your code editor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can parse your Python code into an abstract syntax tree using the **ast** module, and then walk the tree to find the line numbers where division expressions appear.

```
example = """c = 50
b = 100
a = c / b
print(a)
print(a * 50)
print(a / 2)
print("hello")"""

import ast
tree = ast.parse(example)
last_lineno = None
for node in ast.walk(tree):
    # Not all nodes in the AST have line numbers, remember latest one
    if hasattr(node, "lineno"):
        last_lineno = node.lineno

    # If this is a division expression, then show the latest line number
    if isinstance(node, ast.Div):
        print(last_lineno)
```

Comment: And `ast.FloorDiv` for `//`.