# Find Division Operator Instances in C file

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree, pycparser

I am trying to find all division operators in a large c file.
I saw this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54149719/find-all-uses-of-division-operator-in-python-code) for a Python Code.

And I tried to use it for my c file. So, I parsed my c file into ast using pycparser as follows:

```
from pycparser import parse_file, c_parser, c_generator

def translate_to_c(filename):
    ast = parse_file(filename, use_cpp=True)
    ast.show()
translate_to_c('source.c')
```

Then I tried using the example by modifying translate_to_c as follows:

```
def translate_to_c(filename):
    ast = parse_file(filename, use_cpp=True)
    ast.show()
    last_lineno = None
    for node in ast.walk(ast):
        # Not all nodes in the AST have line numbers, remember latest one
        if hasattr(node, "lineno"):
            last_lineno = node.lineno

        # If this is a division expression, then show the latest line number
        if isinstance(node, ast.Div):
            print(last_lineno)
```

I get the following error:

```
line 25, in translate_to_c
    for node in ast.walk(ast):
AttributeError: 'FileAST' object has no attribute 'walk'
```

So any ideas on how I can use this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54149719/find-all-uses-of-division-operator-in-python-code) in my code? or How to loop on the ast file in general ?

Answer (score 2):

Using Python's built-in `ast` library and `pycparser` is very different. One is a Python AST, the other parses C into C ASTs. They are different types from different libraries - you cannot expect one's methods (like `walk`) to just magically work for another!

I recommend you start with pycparser's examples: https://github.com/eliben/pycparser/tree/master/examples

For instance, [this examples](https://github.com/eliben/pycparser/blob/master/examples/func_calls.py) finds all function calls in C code. It should be easy to adjust to find all division operators. The [explore_ast](https://github.com/eliben/pycparser/blob/master/examples/explore_ast.py) example shows you how to feel your way around an AST.